# Unable to establish communication between 'HYPERVSERVER' and 'MYCOMPUTER'

Tags: hyper-v, permissions

I am trying to connect to a Hyper-v server on our network using the Hyper-V Manager. Others on the same network have this working, but when I try to connect to the same server, I just get this text in the **Virtual Machines** section.

> Access Denied. Unable to establish communication between 'HYPERVSERVER' and 'MYCOMPUTER'.

What can be wrong here? My network administrator doesn't understand what's wrong. He has tried to give me access to the server, but this is obviously not enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the 
[Hyper-V Remote Management Configuration Utility](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Hyper-V-Remote-Management-26d127c6). 
Written by [John Howard](http://blogs.technet.com/b/jhoward/) from the MS Hyper-V team.

Comment: This is indeed a good reference. The others in my team has also used this tool to set up the system, but with help from my coworkers on this, it is still not working.

Comment: I ran this command: `cscript hvremote.wsf /show /target:HYPERSERVER`, which reported a problem.  One of the suggestions to fix the problem was to restart the Hyper-V server. We tried this, and now it works.

Comment: The link doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 5):

Usually this is because Windows Vista/7 default DCOM does not allow connections from the outside. To enable follow these steps:

- Run "DCOMCNFG"
- Expand  Component Services Computers My Computer > >.
- Open the properties of My Computer and select the COM Security Tab.
- In the Access Permissions section, click Edit Limits.
- Select ANONYMOUS LOGON and check the Allow for Remote Access permission
- Reopen the Hyper-V Manager and you should be able to administer the Hyper-V server

Comment: Sorry, I have done this now, but no luck.

Comment: "cscript hvremote.wsf /anondcom:grant" does this for you...

Comment: Yes and it doesmore too. it just requires more permissions and takes longer.

Answer (score 1):

Have your tried via IP address or FQDN as alternatives? You might verify that your DNS and/or WINS configurations match up to the other working systems.

Comment: I tried to add the server with IP address, and it automatically resolved to the server name, so this is not the issue.

Comment: And you can ping and/or map successfully as well?

Answer (score 0):

if you are an admin on the remote computer then your problem is most likely network/firewall related